# How to maintain state of ListView items when scrolled?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using a listview with following view as list item

1. TextView
2. ImageView (showing attachment icon)

I am using custom adapter that extends `ArrayAdapter` and uses `ViewHolder`, and in custom adapter I check for condition if an attachment exists. If true, I make `ImageView` visible. Everything works fine, but as I scroll the `ImageView` disappear.

```
public class NoticeListAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private final Activity context;
    private  List<String> img_url = new ArrayList<String>();
    private  List<String>  heading = new ArrayList<String>();
    private  List<Long>  createdDate = new ArrayList<Long>();
    private  List<String>  documentCategoryId = new ArrayList<String>();
    Date date = new Date();

    public NoticeListAdapter(Activity context, List<String> img_url, List<String> heading, List<Long> createdDate, List<String> documentCategoryId) {
        super(context, R.layout.attendance_list_item, heading);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context=context;
        this.img_url = img_url;
        this.heading = heading;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.documentCategoryId = documentCategoryId;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView profilePicture;
        ImageView attachmentIcon;
        TextView txtemployeeName;
        TextView txtbulletinDate;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){

        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(view == null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notice_list_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder.profilePicture = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
            viewHolder.txtemployeeName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.employeeName);
            viewHolder.txtbulletinDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bulletinDate);
            viewHolder.attachmentIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.attachmentIcon);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }


        String description = heading.get(position);
        description = description.length()>40?description.substring(0,40)+"...":description;

        SharedPreferences pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("authDetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getContext());
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(pref.getString("base_url", "")+img_url.get(position), viewHolder.profilePicture);

        viewHolder.txtemployeeName.setText(description);
        viewHolder.txtbulletinDate.setText(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(createdDate.get(position),  date.getTime(),  DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE));

        if(documentCategoryId.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
            viewHolder.attachmentIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change your codes:

```
if(documentCategoryId.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
        viewHolder.attachmentIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

to be:

```
if(documentCategoryId.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
        viewHolder.attachmentIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
else
        viewHolder.attachmentIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Perfect answer, actually when you reuse the views (i.e. using holders) old state of views persist. So you need to reset the image based on current row's scenario

Answer (score 0):

This problem is from your custom `ImageLoader` implementation.

Paste your code, there is some bug which is not displaying image.

Alternatively, you can download image from `URL` and set it as source of `profilePicture` ImageView like this :

```
URL url = new URL(img_url.get(position));
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
viewHolder.profilePicture.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: the problem is with attachmentIcon (ImageView). It works fine, it shows icon for notices that has attachments, but as i scroll down and then go back on top the list refreshes and attachment icon disappears.How do u not let that happen?

Answer (score 0):

You have ViewHolder implementation problem in your code. You don't set holder result to not null view. And also, don't retrieve recently created holder.

Try to change:

```
 view.setTag(viewHolder);
 }else{
 viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
 }
```

to this

```
 view.setTag(viewHolder);
 }
 viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
```

and before `return view;`:

```
view.setTag(viewHolder);
```

Try this, fixed code:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){

    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if(view == null){
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notice_list_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder.profilePicture = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        viewHolder.txtemployeeName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.employeeName);
        viewHolder.txtbulletinDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bulletinDate);
        viewHolder.attachmentIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.attachmentIcon);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();

    String description = heading.get(position);
    description = description.length()>40?description.substring(0,40)+"...":description;

    SharedPreferences pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("authDetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getContext());
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(pref.getString("base_url", "")+img_url.get(position), viewHolder.profilePicture);

    viewHolder.txtemployeeName.setText(description);
    viewHolder.txtbulletinDate.setText(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(createdDate.get(position),  date.getTime(),  DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE));

    if(documentCategoryId.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
        viewHolder.attachmentIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: tried replacing my code with yours, but still no luck.